# Laravel - carbon addDays()

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

Why is it not showing me anything on my blade when I add `$date->addDays(5)`?
Here is my Controller:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
public function index(){

   $date = Carbon::now();
   $date->addDays(5);
   $date->format("Y-m-d");
   $posts = Post::where('status','=', 1)->whereDate('created_at','=', $date)->get();
   return view('home', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
}
...
```

And this is my `home.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">All posts
                    <a href="/posts/create" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 70%">New post +</a></div>
                <hr>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @foreach($posts as $post)
                        @if($post->status == 1)
                            <small style="color:red">PREMIUM POST</small>
                            <hr>
                        @endif
                        <h2>{{$post->name}}</h2><br>
                        <medium>{{$post->body}}</medium>
                        <hr style="border: 1.5px solid grey">
                    @endforeach
                    <small><?php echo now() ?></small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

What is solution to this problem? It doesn't showing me anything in my blade after I add `$date->addDays(5);`?

EDITED : I just need my posts to be visible for 5 days and after that not. That's all, maybe the mistake is with `addDays();` because if i delete it my blade is now showing me posts but only for today.

Comment: `$date->format("Y-m-d");` returns a text string in that format, it does not set a default formatting

Comment: did it really have datas after 5days?

Comment: And `echo now()` is not even using the carbon variable anyway

Comment: No, it doesn't show any datas after 5 days. I deleted line ```$date->format("Y-m-d")``` and nothing happens. All I need is that these posts made today shows for next 5 days and after 5 days to "disapear" from blade.

Comment: I know it doesn't use carbon variable, but that is not the point of this question

Answer (score 5):

The `created_at` is created by `current_timestamp`,
if you use `addDays(5)` will get the posts from feature. That's impossible.

Honestly, you can add the field named `expired_date` and compared with this field will be pretty easy.

use laravel migration to add a field, like

```php
$table->date('expired_date');
```

And once you create the post, you need to set the expired_date with `Carbon::now()->addDays(5)`;

And filter the expired date greater than today.

```php
public function index(){

   $date = Carbon::now();
   $date->addDays(5);
   $posts = Post::where('status','=', 1)->whereDate('created_at','>=', $date)->get();
   return view('home', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

If your `status` field just to distinguish expired or not expired, I think you don't need this field.

However, if you really need this field to maintain the expired status.

you need to update it every day, try to use [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling)

```php
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            Post::where('expired_date', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::today())->update(['status' => 0]);
        })->daily();
    }
```

Comment: Sir thank you for your answer. Can you tell me how can I add ```expired_date``` field please? I'm struggling with this all day

Comment: use laravel migration to add a field, like `$table->date('expired_date')`;  And once you create the post, you need to set the expired_date with `Carbon::now()->addDays(5)`

Comment: It showing me error ```Field 'expired' doesn't have a default value```, i named it ```expired```.

Comment: Okay sorry my typo mistake

Comment: I added expired in my posts table and I added ```Carbon::now()->addDays(5)``` to it. Now I need some ```if``` statement to show it for 5 days in my blade?

Comment: @Milos why don't you just filter them in your controller action, like just filter the expired date greater than today.

Comment: I just did it and it works all fine. I'm sorry but is there any way to set this ```expired``` field according to ```status```? If ```status``` field is = 1 than add five days to ```expired```. I did this to my ```PostsController``` but it doesn't changing ```expired``` value

Answer (score 0):

You can add with custom date format

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y.m.d', $premiumDate);
$daysAdd = 2;
$date = $date->addDays($daysAdd);
dd($date);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$date= Carbon::now()->addDays(5);
$posts = Post::where('status','=', 1)->whereDate('created_at','=', $date)->get();
   
return view('home', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
```

Comment: What does this add to [TsaiKoga's 2020 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59705257)?

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.